# CMS block only on first category page

Tags: php, magento, block, categories

I'm using Magento 1.9 and struggling on one thing.
I have a CMS block in my category page but I want it to show only on the first page! So if I scroll down and move to page 2 on the same category I don't want to see that CMS block again.
I tried to put this code in the CMS block... but it ignores me
(category-accordion.accordion is the main div of the CMS block)

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?p=") >-1) 
{document.getElementsByClassName('category-accordion accordion')[0].display='none';}
// ]]></script>
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

tried the following code on the category page:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode() && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?=p') !== true)): ?>
   <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
   <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode() && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?=p') !== false)): ?>
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
 <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set condition in Category View Template `catalog\category\view.phtml`.

```
<?php 
$currentPage = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1);
if($currentPage <= 1) { 
echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml()
} ?>
```

Comment: I modified the file like this but it seems wrong (does not upload the page anymore): `<?php 
$currentPage = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1);
?>

<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
        <?php 
        if($currentPage <= 1) { 
        echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml()
        } ?>
        <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
        
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: **EDIT**: I modified the file like this but it seems to ignore the condition (shows the block): `<?php if($this->isContentMode()) {
     echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml();
     $currentPage = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('p', 1);
   }
    else if($this->isMixedMode() && $currentPage <= 1) {
        echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml();
        echo $this->getProductListHtml();
    }  
    else if($this->isMixedMode() && $currentPage > 1) {
        echo $this->getProductListHtml();
    }
    else {
        echo $this->getProductListHtml();
    }
?>`

Comment: you first comment code was correct. Can you please let me know what issue you are facing in that

Comment: It seems that Magento checks the condition only on the first page and then keep the block... example: if I put `$currentPage > 1` the CMS block is not shown in the first page and ALSO not shown in the following pages, instead if I put `$currentPage <= 1` it shows it on all pages.

Comment: Can you please echo `$currentPage` variable for each page. Because for me it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<script>
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?p=") >-1) 
    {
        jQuery('.category-accordion.accordion').hide();
    }
</script>
```